# Providing permission on Mount point within Windows Server Using powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to provide access to a user on mount point which is present inside D drive in Windows server. We are using `Set-Acl` command.

```bsh
$Acl = Get-Acl "D:\MountPointName"
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("username", "FullControl","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
Set-Acl "D:\MountPointName" $Acl
```

This is not working.

Comment: "This is not working" ... *how?* Are you getting an error? What are the actual and expected results?

Comment: we are actually trying to create a PS script using which we can give access on the mount points remotely. we are new to power-shell actually.